# Is nesting tables with bootstrap Vue a good way to achieve this?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, frontend, bootstrap-vue

I had to solve a specific problem that I'm going to explain using an image to better understand the question.

Basically the result that I wanted to obtain is this:
[image]

The white rows are the main items and the gray ones are subitems of the main. To achieve this with Bootstrap Vue tables I pass to the main table (the one contained in every accordion tab) the array with all the main items, and every main item has his subItems set contained in an array. Now to render the grey rows for every white row I used the row details slot in which I put another b-table that receives as items the subItems of the main row.

This solution looks fine but it comes with some important problems:

- first of all I had to reset the row-details padding in order to align the outer table with the inner table, but it still has some differences in width (if you look close between the TDs there are some differences)
- as second point, the most important one, every row has to be selectable only one per time, in order to modify the infos contained inside. At the moment I set the outer table selectable with only one row per time, and same for the inner tables, but since these are more than one it creates conflicts every time I select rows on different subitems or if I select a main item together with one or more subitems.

Now my question is:
before I proceed finding a solution maintaining the actual structure that I built, I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve this without nesting tables and at the same time maintaining the actual look of the entire table.

If this can help, I post the piece of code related to the result seen in the above image:

```
// OUTER TABLE
<b-table 
  :items="dataTable.itemsOnDesktop"
  :fields="billOfMaterialsType == '2' ? dataTable.fields : dataTable.fieldsA1" 
  :selectable="isSelectable"
  @row-selected="onRowSelected"
  ref="selectableTable" 
  outlined
  sticky-header="700px" 
  head-variant="light"
  select-mode="single" 
  stacked="md"
  selected-variant="danger"
  details-td-class="row-details-styling"
  id="outer-project-table"
  bordered
  fixed
  :busy="tableBusy"
>
 .
 .
 .
 <template 
  v-if="billOfMaterialsType == '2'"
  #row-details="row"
>
  // INNER TABLE
  <b-table 
    id="inner-project-table"
    hover 
    table-variant="secondaryLight"
    selected-variant="danger" 
    select-mode="single"
    @row-selected="onRowSelected" 
    :selectable="isSelectable"
    thead-class="hidden_header"
    :fields="dataTable.fields" 
    :items="row.item.node.bomiteminfoSet.edges"
    :ref="`innerTable-${row.item.node.id}`"
    bordered
    small
    fixed
  >
    .
    .
    .
  </b-table>
</template>
</b-table>
```

And here it is a short example of the dataTable.itemsOnDesktop json structure:

```
[{
  "node": {
    "id": "Qk9NSXRllE2vZGU6MjA2MzU=",
    "code": "1.4.7.2.a",
    "description": " INTONACO COMPLETO AL CIVILE PREMISCELATO A PROIEZIONE ...",
    "quantity": "1290.00",
    "unitOfMeasurement": "m2",
    "bomiteminfoSet": {
      "edges": [{
        "node": {
          "id": "Qk9YinRlbUalk87230mGlOjExOTkx",
          "code": null,
          "description": "PORZIONE BURLOTTI\npiano interrato, piano terra",
          "parts": "955.00",
          "length": null,
          "width": null,
          "heightOrWeight": null,
          "unitOfMeasurement": null,
          "quantity": "955.00"
        }
      },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "Qk9ld5RlSXRlbUaOb2RlOjExOTky",
            "code": null,
            "description": "PORZIONE LAZZARINI\npiano terra",
            "parts": "335.00",
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "heightOrWeight": null,
            "unitOfMeasurement": null,
            "quantity": "335.00"
          }
      }]
    }
  },
  "isActive": true,
  "_showDetails": true
}]
```

Let me know your ideas about this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Could you please share one example of the `dataTable.itemsOnDesktop` to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sure, I added a short example because the other one was way too long.

Comment: I implement one sample to reproduce your question in fiddle but I couldn't see the conflicts when selecting the rows. Can you look at it and tell me how can I reproduce your issue? https://jsfiddle.net/impala69/pg536yht/1/

Comment: The conflict I am referring to is that ideally the outer table should be like a single table, so if i select a main row and then a subItem, the first one should deselect. One of the main reasons why I'm trying to achieve this is because I have to use different mutations for the main items and for the subItems. Perhaps I should have clarified this thing about the different mutations to better understand the issue. My bad. Anyway thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Ok, please look at this https://jsfiddle.net/impala69/14ry6hkc/44/ fiddle and see if your issue is fixed. I didn't answer the question because I'm not sure If I understand the problem properly.